# In RSA encryption algorithm, Can we find P and Q, if we have totient of N

Tags: encryption, numbers, rsa, computation-theory, number-theory

Totient(N) is a product of (P-1)(Q-1) and (P-1),(Q-1) will not be prime after taken 1 from them and multiple factors can be obtained? Is it true? Or can we find P and Q if we have totient of N?

Comment: All the calculations can be found [Why is it important that phi(n) is kept a secret, in RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5791/why-is-it-important-that-phin-is-kept-a-secret-in-rsa)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  This is not a programming question.  I invite you to ask this question at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only even prime is 2, rest of primes are odd. Therefore $p-1$ is an even number that can at least has 2 as a divisor.

For the second part of your questions; What you do is playing with the equations;

φ(n)=(p−1)(q−1)=pq−p−q+1=(n+1)−(p+q)

(n+1)−φ(n)=p+q

(n+1)−φ(n)−p=q

and n=pq to obtain this quadratic formula.

p2−(n+1−φ(n))p+n=0

For more details and an example see; [Why is it important that phi(n) is kept a secret, in RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5791/why-is-it-important-that-phin-is-kept-a-secret-in-rsa)

Comment: Can we find P and Q if we have Totient(N) ??